# Exception Causes ModelBinding To Fail

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

If I receive a generic error in my ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Beta app and catch it.  I notice that the next time I post that the model returned to my post is always null.  Do I need to clear out the ModelState error or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were pulling from TempData onModelCreated.  When an error occured, TempData was cleared out.